# "The caller was not authenticated by the service" error when running automated tests

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm building an application that interfaces heavily with MSDCRM 2011 through the WCF service, using AD-based authentication but manually specifying credentials at runtime. This app is TDDed and therefore we have a sizable test suite, some of which interfaces with a development instance of CRM to ensure that code and developer alike are generating not only syntactically valid queries, but executable and correct ones (which as most Linq-savvy people know is not a guarantee when running your query against a mock or sim; there's always a limitation of the queryable provider that makes a beautiful query against an in-memory collection fail on the real system).

Frequently, as in at least once a day, multiple fixtures' worth of tests that touch the web service will fail for at least one developer with the error message:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException : The caller was not authenticated by the service.
  ----> System.ServiceModel.FaultException : The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
```

All of these same tests will have passed on the previous run, and will pass again after some uncertain time between attempts. This seems to happen after the tests have been run a few times in quick succession, especially on one machine. Once it's happened, when the user account in question is used to log into Remote Desktop on a terminal server, RD returns the more helpful error that the user account is locked. All this makes me think this is some sort of intrusion detection/prevention measure in our domain system that the multiple logins are tripping (maybe it looks like a DoS or crackbot attack). However, our IT department which maintains the domain has no clue what is doing this, as they don't knowingly enforce any such ruleset for successful logins (only failed ones), and so they're insisting it's a CRM problem (and therefore the Development team's responsibility).

I realize it's not much for you guys to go on, but if it is CRM locking the account, where would I change the settings (ideally for the one user account used for the tests), and if it's not CRM but something in the Windows domain/AD system, where can I tell the IT team to look to change these settings (again ideally for just the one user)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the presence of incorrect saved credentials for the CRM server in the Windows Credential Store; these credentials are regularly tried by Windows, even when the user or running programs are not trying to connect, and these tries count against the number of authentication failures before lockout. Removing the stored credentials from the credential store has solved the problem.